# Need to increase variable by 1 with math for every x loops

Tags: loops, math, vector, lua

```
i = 0
while i < 84 do
    something.Position(vectorPosInit()+Vector(0,i,20+(i%12)*12))
end
```

My question is this:
How can I make the variable i increase with 1 for every 12 loops without making a new variable but using math?

Where it says HERE it should increase by only 1 every 12 loops using only var i and math

Vector(0,(HERE),20+(i%12)*12)

Comment: What programmming language are you using?

Comment: I am using lua.

Comment: You will need a counter for the number of loops, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

```
local i = 0
for n = 1,84 do
    if n%12==0 then
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

You mean something like that?

Comment: Wait, no this is not what I need at all, sorry.

Comment: I need (HERE) to increase by 1 every 12 loops without changing the variable. And HERE is variable i with a possible mathematical solution.

Comment: @janemcplain I am increasing `i` by 1 every 12 loops.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround

```
i = 0
while i < 84 do
    something.Position(vectorPosInit()+Vector(0,math.floor(i/12),20+(i%12)*12))
end
```

By adding math.floor(i/12), is this a viable solution?

Comment: Yes, this is very straightforward and most usual solution.

Comment: `for i = 0,83 do` is a bit shorter

Comment: `for y = 0,6 do for z = 20,152,12 do ...+Vector(0,y,z) end end` is the same but more easy to understand.